# VS2010 Project Template + VMSDK

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dsl-tools, vsix

For the life of me, I can't get my DSL project to be exported as a template, other than the default ItemTemplate (as in Add New Item)

Does anyone happen to have a summary of what has to be done to be able to create a new project? VSTemplate follows. Have tried adding the zip to the VSIX as Content (ProjTemplate) to no avail.

```
<!--DSL Tools Language Template-->
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" Type="Item" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <TemplateData>
        <Name Package="{602c1894-d640-407a-a311-aca9d5ab7a5c}" ID="103"/>
        <Description Package="{602c1894-d640-407a-a311-aca9d5ab7a5c}" ID="102"/>
        <Icon Package="{602c1894-d640-407a-a311-aca9d5ab7a5c}" ID="201" />
        <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
        <SortOrder>360</SortOrder>
        <DefaultName>FlowDsl.mhf</DefaultName>
    </TemplateData>
    <TemplateContent>
        <ProjectItem TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.mhf">mhf.mhf</ProjectItem>
        <ProjectItem TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.mhf.diagram">mhf.diagram</ProjectItem>
    </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

Thanks;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want a project template, correct? For starters, the Type attribute on the VSTemplate element should be `Type="Project"` instead of `Type="Item"`. Additionally, [project templates need to have](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/project-element-visual-studio-templates?view=vs-2019&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2015) a `<Project>` element (usually a csproj/vbproj file) in the `<TemplateContent>` to use as a starter project.

I would suggest creating a C# or VB project with an instance of your DSL as a project item (and structuring the project as you would want your template). Then, try using the [Export Template Wizard](https://web.archive.org/web/20101223145651/http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com:80/en-us/57320b20-34a2-42e4-b97e-e615c71aca24) to create a VSIX with your project template.

If you want to further customize and control what is in the template, check out [this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/creating-and-sharing-project-item-templates/) which describes how to manually author and package your templates.

Comment: I want an item template as well as a project template - I guess what you say and what I have now will work.